# How to load an icon with transparent background and display it correctly with C++ / OpenGL?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, icons, transparent

I am currently trying to load an icon which has a transparent background.

Then I create a bitmap from it and try to display the bits via glTexImage2D().

But the background of the icon never gets transparent :(

Here is some of my code:

```
DWORD dwBmpSize = 32*32*4;
byte* bmBits = new byte[dwBmpSize];

for(unsigned int i = 0; i <dwBmpSize; i+=4)
{
    bmBits[i] = 255;  // R
    bmBits[i+1] = 0;  // G
    bmBits[i+2] = 0;  // B
    bmBits[i+3] = 255;// A
    // I always get a red square, no matter what value i fill into alpha
}

//create texture from bitmap
glTexImage2D(target, 0,
    GL_RGBA, 32, 32,
    0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bmBits);

delete bmBits;
```

Edit: I changed the code, to be sure, that my bits have an alpha channel.
Now I am filling a 32x32 pxl area with custom values to see, what happens, instead of loading an icon. It still does not work!

What am I missing? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: I do not know that API, but `DIB_RGB_COLORS` looks fishy, misses an `A` in `RGB`. Maybe research the raw values of `bmp->bmBits` to see whether there are alpha values at all after `GetDIBIts`.

Comment: It's certainly possible, you are doing something wrong

Comment: Okay, now I changed my code, so I am sure, that there is an alpha channel. I got rid of the GetDIBits() stuff. But it still does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable blending and set the correct blend mode.

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Also if you fill the entire alpha channel with 255 it will still be opaque. Try 128 or something instead.

Comment: I tried it with 0 and now it is completely transparent! Big thx to you sir!